# Asp net print a Dictionary value at the view file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to print a value by key from a dictionary but I cannot figure out how should be.
I wrote to the controller this:

```
var a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
a["b"] = "s";

ViewData["a"] = a;
```

and at the view file:

```
<h1><%= ((Dictionary<string, string>) ViewData["a"])["b"] %></h1>
```

or also so:

```
<h1>@a["b"]</h1>
```

In the first case, I got literally this: "<%: ((Dictionary) ViewData["a"])["b"] %>". The second is a NullReferenceException.

I have been trying to find the solution but all time I could find just solutions by foreach loop.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `<h1>@(((Dictionary<string, string>)ViewData["a"])["b"])</h1>`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid casting to dictionary in the view file, you can use `ViewBag` to access the same data:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.a["b"]</h1>
```

Or if you want to use `ViewData` you can use such code:

```
<h1>@((ViewData["a"] as Dictionary<string,string>)["b"])</h1>
```